# show post from the same category when you click previous/next button wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, post, categories

I have the below issue. When I click to the previous/next button of the same category unfortunately i receive the previous/next post hronologically instead of the previous/next post of the same category.

Here is the code:

```
< div id="previous_post">
< ?php previous_post_link( '%link', __( '<span class="prev"><< Preivous Post</span>', 'esquire' ) ); ? > 
< /div>

< div id="next_post">   < ?php next_post_link( '%link', __( '<span class="next">Next Post >></span>',  'esquire' ) ); ? >

< /div>
```

I've tried to fix my problem with this article http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link
but something i am doing wrong.

Any advice please?

Comment: you might want to keep reading further down till you see something like
 <?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next post in category', TRUE, '13'); ?>

Comment: Hey @xlordt. I have already tried the parameter TRUE, but it didn't help. Of course, i am not sure if i put it at the correct place.

Comment: how exactly did you try this? can you update your post with solutions that you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example

```
 previous_post_link( '%link', __( '<span class="prev"><< Preivous Post</span>', TRUE, 'esquire' ) );
```

I don't want to specify every time each category. I want this to be done automatically. For example, when it shows the posts from category machine and you open to read the first post, when you click to next post, then you must see next post of the same category not the next post in general. If the category is food, then the next post of the same category.

I was clear or I confused you more?

Comment: OOOOOOHHH GOD, what a failure! You are right xlordt. I was trying to put TRUE in a wrong place. I put it between the two last parenthesis, and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the single.php page from your Parent theme and Paste it to your Child-theme's directory. Open the single.php from child-theme directory and add the following code at the end of file [before get_footer(); ]

```
<?php
$post_id = $post->ID; // Get current post ID
$cat = get_the_category(); 
$current_cat_id = $cat[0]->cat_ID; // Get current Category ID 

$args = array('category'=>$current_cat_id,'orderby'=>'post_date','order'=> 'DESC');
$posts = get_posts($args);
// Get IDs of posts retrieved by get_posts function
$ids = array();
foreach ($posts as $thepost) {
    $ids[] = $thepost->ID;
}
// Get and Echo the Previous and Next post link within same Category
$index = array_search($post->ID, $ids);
$prev_post = $ids[$index-1];
$next_post = $ids[$index+1];
?>

<?php if (!empty($prev_post)){ ?> <a class="previous-post" rel="prev" href="<?php echo get_permalink($prev_post) ?>"> <span class="meta-icon"><i class="fa fa-angle-left fa-lg"></i></span> Previous</a> <?php } ?>

<?php if (!empty($next_post)){ ?> <a class="next-post" rel="next" href="<?php echo get_permalink($next_post) ?>">Next <span class="meta-icon"><i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-lg"></i></span> </a> <?php } ?>
```

After adding this code, paste the following code into your child-theme's Style.css to style the links:

```
a.previous-post, a.next-post {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4498e7;
    text-align: center;
    height: 34px;
    line-height: 34px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

a.previous-post:hover, a.next-post:hover {
    color: #4498e7;
    background-color: #fff;
}

a.previous-post {
    float: left !important;
}

a.next-post {
    float: right !important;
}
```

To see these links in actions, visit my website: [www.techtutsonline.com](http://www.techtutsonline.com/implicit-remoting-windows-powershell/)

Let me know the results :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final/correct syntax

```
    previous_post_link( '%link', __( '<span class="prev"><< Previous Post</span>', 'esquire' ), TRUE );
```

Thank you!